# Simple simple Euler Lagrange Equation

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations, physics, calculus-of-variations

Just starting a course on Lagrangian Mechanics and I'm just wondering what about the Euler-Lagrange equation, and more specifically what I'm meant to be trying to do ..

One of the questions from my textbook reads :

Solve the Euler-Lagrange equation for the following function
\begin{align*}
f(y,y') = y^2+y'^2
\end{align*}
Looks simple enough... But where should I be headed to start?

The Euler-Lagrange Equation as we have it is
\begin{align*}
\frac{\partial f}{\partial y} = \frac{d}{dx} \frac{\partial f}{\partial y'}
\end{align*}

Do I just find the partial derivatives of f treating y and y' as independent variables as follows:

$$\frac{\partial f}{\partial y} = 2y,$$
$$\frac{\partial f}{\partial y'} = 2y$$
so then we have :
$$2y = \frac{d}{dx}(2y')$$
$$y = \frac{d}{dx}(y')$$
$$yx+c = y'$$
$$\frac{yx^2}{2}+cx+d = y$$

And then simplify with the y isolated on the right so it looks nice .. or at least thats what I thought..

Any comments ? right track, wrong track? 
Also, what is this euler equation actually solving for? Is it just a nice way of solving differential equations in this form ?

When we did this in class, we did a monster proof showing it minimizes the path between 2 points or finds the extrema for the function $I(x) = \int^a_b \ F(y(x),y'(x),x) dx,$ which is all great but I'm not too sure how this relates to the equation we solve in the question .. Thanks for all

Comment: you seem to be 'losing' derivatives. $\frac{d}{dx} y' = y^{''}$. At least if $y=y(x)$. Then $y=y^{''}$ is the ODE you have to solve. Also,  $\frac{df}{dy'} = 2 y'$, but that you fixed later on somehow, so it was possibly only a typo.

Comment: How did you go from $y=\frac{d}{dx}y\,'$ to $yx+c=y\,'$? Did you perhaps do $\int ydx=yx+c$ (which is incorrect)?

Comment: $y$ and $y'$ are not independent of $x$, so you cannot solve $y = \frac{d}{dx}y'$ this way.

Comment: Though you *are* correct that we keep $y$ and $y\,'$ independent when we take *partial* derivatives.

Comment: ok, so the problem line seems to be $y = \frac{d}{dx}(y')$ .. from here I should've gone to $y = y''$ which is easy enough to solve.. The reason I can't just integrate both sides with respect to $x$ is because the $y$ on the LHS is dependent of $x$ .. Can somebody confirm these thoughts for me ? thanks thanks

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The function $f(y,y') = {y'}^2+y^2$ can be interpreted as a Lagrangian $L = T-V$, where $T={y'}^2$ is the kinetic energy and $V = -y^2$ the potential energy of some object.${}^\dagger$
Among other things, *this is the Lagrangian of pencil that is balanced vertically on its tip.*
$y$ is then interpreted as the angle the pencil makes with the vertical, and must be assumed to be small.
$x$ should be interpreted as time.
We expect at least one unstable solution since the pencil can fall over.

The action is extremized by solutions to the Euler-Lagrange equation.
The equations of motion found by the principle of least action are equivalent to Newton's laws of motion---we are going to find out how the pencil drops.

First, note that
$$\begin{eqnarray*}
\frac{d}{dx} \frac{\partial f}{\partial y'}
&=& \frac{d}{dx} 2 y' \\
&=& 2y'' \\
\frac{\partial f}{\partial y}
&=& 2 y.
\end{eqnarray*}$$
The Euler-Lagrange equation gives
$$y'' = y.$$
The solutions are
$$y(x) = A e^x + B e^{-x},$$
where $A$ and $B$ are some constants determined by the initial conditions.
For example, if $y(0)=0$ and $y'(0)=1$ we find
$$y(x) = \sinh x.$$
This solution is indeed unstable, the angle increases without bound.
Of course, this can only be taken seriously for small $y$.

The principal advantage of finding equations of motion in this way is it allows the simple use of [generalized coordinates](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Generalized_coordinates).
With practice it becomes automatic to write the total kinetic and potential energy of a system in terms of some convenient coordinates and to find the equations of motion via the Euler-Lagrange equations, which have the same form for any system of generalized coordinates.
As a cultural side note, be aware that [variational methods](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Calculus_of_variations) extend far beyond their application to the Lagrangian formulation of classical mechanics.

---

<sub>${}^\dagger$The force corresponding to this potential is $F = -\frac{d}{dy}V = 2y$. This is Hooke's law with the wrong sign.
What happens if $f(y,y') = {y'}^2 - y^2$?</sub>

Comment: Thank you so much ! I have a hopeless lecturer (who is indeed very smart but who can't seem to teach and is very impatient) so I am badly in need of a better approach... I may be putting down a lot of questions in the next few months :/

Comment: So in the final y(x)=sinhx , does the x then represent time (oh wait, you told me that).. 

as for the †, would $f(y, y')=y'^2 - y^2$ then be the Lagrangian of a spring ?

Comment: @Ronald: Glad to help. Yes, if you flip the sign you can also think of it as the Lagrangian of a pendulum for small oscillations. You'll get simple harmonic motion.